# Detect Image with good contrast and well textured

Tags: ios, swift

I have a requirement where user click image and I have to check whether that clicked image will be compatible for AR Image trackable.

Example of good image as shown in WWDC
[image: wi]

Answer (score 3):

ARReferenceImage's [validate()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage/3194594-validate) function will determine whether image is suitable for ARKit image tracking, when you can't upload image through xcode

Comment: This is available only for iOS 13. I need iOS 12 support too. So any other way by which I can know Image will be supported for AR? Like with OpenCV to determine ?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from the question. Their rules are too broadly described to be recreated without significant effort. You can get an estimation with cv::calcHist and cv::goodFeaturesToTrack

Comment: Can you please help with demo of cv::calcHist. I Tried that but it needs many parameters like OutputArray corner, maxCorners.

Comment: That's kind of my point. If you'd try to recreate validate() method in OpenCV you'd need to find the right constants by trial and error and even that relies on the assumption that they use the same or similar method to find out if an image has "Distinct features" or "Repetitive structures".